# How to change the "available" to another word in website references (IEETran)?

Tags: babel, ieeetran

I am using overleaf and writing an article using IEEEtran.

I am trying to add a reference to a website, like this:

```
  @online{cni2021,
  author="{Confederação Nacional da Indústria}",
  title="{Portal CNI - Institucional}",
  url={http://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/cni/institucional/},
  note="(acesso em 3 de Junho de 2021)",
  }
```

The issue is that in references the URL appears this way:
"Available: [http://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/cni/institucional/"](http://www.portaldaindustria.com.br/cni/institucional/%22)

I would like to replace the word "Available" to the brazilian portuguese translation, that is "Disponível".

I tried to add the code below, but it didn`t work:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{
  urlseen = {Disponivel}
}
```

Even changing that bibliografphy strings to "portuguese" or to "english", it does not take any effect.

I also already have the code below in my tex file:

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectbiblanguage{brazil}
```

But nothing appears to work. After some hours trying to solve this without any success, can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try add `urlfrom` field.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{%
urlfrom = {Disponivel},
urlseen = {Visitou em}
}
```